# How can I write multiple % in url in figure?

Tags: url, percent-sign

I have something like that:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.17,angle=00]{some_images.jpg}
    \caption[The_caption}
    \textbf{\textit{Source :}} https://some_domain/...%C3%A8.._....
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

If I just write it this way, in rendered document, the URL stop at

> https://some_domain/...

I know that `%` can be inserted in text using `\%`
If I rewrite my URL this way:

```
https://some_domain/...\%C3%A8...
```

Rendered text read:

> https://some_domain/...%C3

But, I need to add `\` twice, then if I rewrite my URL this way:

```
https://some_domain/...\%C3\%A8..
```

I get error

> ! Missing $ inserted. $... (then my
> URL)

---

Also tried using the URL in `\href{}{}`, which is what I usually use for URLs , but escaping `%` twice on the same line still ends in error.

Comment: please don't show only snippets. It is much easier to test your issue and solutions if you show a small but complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The URL also included underscores further in the URL. (This info was not in original post because I didn't think that they were relevant.)

What happened was that escaping both % made the undescrores "appear" and crash the code...
So when I escape the underscores (`\_`) the way `\%` is escaped, this solves this issue.

Also,`%C3%A8` actually stand for `è` in encoded URL, so I just replaced it, yet escaped the underscores.

Comment: Because of unicode characters, you should use `\href`.

Comment: No, as mentionned in qestion, \href didn't solve the issue. But apparently underscores need to be escaped in LaTeX, which I didn't know. (I'm using \href any way because that's my defautlt way for presenting URL currently, but it's not \href that solves the issue.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use `\url` from `url` package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.17,angle=00]{example-image}
            \caption{The caption}
        \textbf{\textit{Source :}} \url{https://some_domain/...%C3%A8...}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, use `\centering` instead of `center` environment within a float.

Comment: If you want the url be displayed as normal text, you can add `\urlstyle{same}` in the preamble.